# C++ While loop in an infinite loop even on correct answer

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

For some reason, this very simple while loops keeps infinitely looping. Perhaps I've been staring at this too long or made some real obvious, foolish mistake. Can someone help me fix the code? I tried typing "ste" but it keeps on giving me the output of invalid.

```
while (type1 != "nor" || type1 != "fir" || type1 != "wat" || type1 != "ele" || type1 != "gra" || type1 != "ice" || type1 != "fig"|| type1 != "poi" || type1 != "gro" || type1 != "fly" || type1 != "psy" || type1 != "bug" || type1 != "roc" || type1 != "gho" || type1 != "dra" || type1 != "dar" || type1 != "ste" || type1 != "fai" || type1 != "n/a")
{
    cout << "Invalid type. Re-enter type." << endl;
    cin >> type1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `"ste"` fell off your screen. With lines that long, you never know... :)

Comment: use &&, your condition is always true

Comment: [Short circuit evalutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). When you say `a || b`, if `a` is `true`, `b` is never checked.

Comment: Ahh!! Of course it was the logical AND. I've been staring at the screen far too long. What a noobish mistake of me. Thank you!

Comment: Happens to everyone, don't believe anyone denying it :)

Comment: And a tip: don't write such long conditions. Use a container/dicitonary of strings with all possible values and then *search* through it.

Comment: It's a quick program I was whipping up. I just got hung on this one part for about half an hour and it was bothering me. Otherwise, I wouldn't have written such a long condition statement. Haha. :)

Comment: _'this very simple while loop'_ ?????!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible for this loop to ever end. The only possible way this look could end would be for `type1` to be `nor`, `fir`, `wat`, ... at the same time. You probably want to replace all ors (`||`), by ands (`&&`). In that case your loop would stop at the moment `type1` is equal to one of the compared strings (`nor`, `fir`, `wat`... ), which of course is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition will always be true, for any given value of type1, is has to be different than all the values you specify save (at most) one.

If you use && instead of || you would get what you intended to achieve