# While loop not acting as expected in Dev C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get a while loop to accept the condition of looping until the values 1 or 2 are entered using the code below

```
while((choice != 1) || (choice != 2))
{
    cout << "\nEnter 1 to read a file, Enter 2 to enter your own values: ";
    cin >> choice;
}
```

As best as I can remember this has worked for me previously so I'm not sure why it's not working now and I think it may be something to do with how I installed Dev C++ as per the screenshot linked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd2fa.png). I vaguely recall having to fix this issue on my old PC but can't remember how to fix it exactly. Any help with either explaining where I've gone wrong in the code or how to fix the Dev C++ error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Name a number that's not 1 or not 2 *at the same time*.

Comment: || should be && - you want to repeat while the number is not 1 or 2, but you instead have made a condition that can never be false since every number is either not 1 or not 2 (or both)

Comment: It's also not 1980 any more, so these kinds of interfaces are just plain annoying. Try writing programs that use `argv` instead, read command-line arguments. Give your commands names. `./myprog read` or `./myprog update` is a lot easier to use than displaying menus of options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ While loop in an infinite loop even on correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610286/c-while-loop-in-an-infinite-loop-even-on-correct-answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your loop is that this condition:

```
(choice != 1) || (choice != 2)
```

is guaranteed to be true for *every* value. If `choice` is 1, the second clause of the disjunction will be true; if it's 2, the first clause will be true; if it's any other number both will be true. If *any* of the clauses are true in a disjunction, the entire condition is true. This means your condition will always be true.

What you need is a conjunction of the clauses:

```
(choice != 1) && (choice != 2)
           // ^^
```

With this the loop condition will only be true when *both* clauses are true, and this requires `choice` to be something other than 1 or 2.

Comment: Thanks the explanation helps a lot, I was thinking that it would loop if the value was not one or two as opposed to looping when the value is not one and not two (basically misunderstanding how the loop functions).

Answer (score 1):

If choice is equal to 1, one of your conditions is false but the other is still true.  It is similar when choice is 2.  Change your "OR" statement to an "AND" and it should only loop when the user enters something other than one or two.